# pass parameter to form from template in Django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

in Django I make a form which get an email address and save it in database and this my form.py:

```
class NewsletterUserSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsletterUsers
        fields = ['email']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        return email
```

and this is my views.py :

```
def newsletter_signup(request):
    form = NewsletterUserSignUpForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if NewsletterUsers.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            messages.warning(request, 'Your Email Already Exist In Our DataBase.',
                             'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible')
        else:
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your Has Been Submitted To Our DataBase.',
                             'alert alert-success alert-dismissible')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'newsletter/subscribe.html', context)
```

the problem is here that this form has it own input which the input must put inside it but I want to design my own template and get input in my template then pass it to this form and my question is how do I can pass inputs in my .html template file to my form?

this is my html file and don't know to put what in href for input tag :

```
<form method="post" class="login100-form validate-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-43">
                        Subscribe
                    </span>
                    <div>
                        <inputtype="email" name="Email">
                        <span class="label">Email</span>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" href="">
                            Subscribe
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

and what should I put in my href and how pass input to form from here?
**In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem it was for my html code, I Should add an id and name attribute to my input tag and use this id and name for getting input from html and pass it to my form, and for href attribute I write the url that redirect to my form.
fixed html code:

```
<form method="post" class="login100-form validate-form">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-43">
                        Subscribe
                    </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 container-login100-form-btn rs1 rs2 validate-input padding-50"
                     data-validate="Username is required">
                    <input id="email" maxlength="100" class="input100" type="email" name="email">
                    <span class="label-input100">Email</span>
                </div>


                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button type="submit" href="{% url 'newsletter_subscribe' %}" class="login100-form-btn">
                        Subscribe
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center w-full p-t-23">
                    <a style="font-size: 15px" href="{% url 'newsletter_unsubscribe' %}" class="txt1">
                        Click Here To Unsubscribe.
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to create your own custom input box and when that box is filled, you want the form input box to also get filled.

Hide the form input box using display:none. 
Create your own custom input box, use javascript to fill the form input box when custom input box is filled.
Ex :

```
<script>
   form_input_box = document.getElementById('id_of_form_input_box')
   custom_input_box = documen.getElementById('id_of_custom_input_box')

   $("id_of_custom_input_box").change(function(){
   form_input_box.value = custom_input_box.value
   });
</script>
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how pass the value to my django form, I know how to receive the value, but I don't know how pass it to django database to store.